# Как кликнуть на элемент из консоли?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Как из консоли кликнуть на эту кнопку?

```
<div class="button like" onclick="like("f9f54b8bf5fa3f979b205e61")" status="off">
<div class="icon" icon="like"></div>
<span>32</span>
</div>
```

Делаю вот так, но клик не происходит, даже число не меняется.

```
document.body.querySelector('.like').click();

Пробовал ещё вот так:
document.querySelector('.like').click()
```

Comment: У меня ощущение, что вот это вот не работает `onclick="like("f9f54b8bf5fa3f979b205e61")"`, попробуйте заменить на `onclick="like('f9f54b8bf5fa3f979b205e61')"`

Comment: Он по классу даже не кликает, зайдите на colorhunt.co и попробуйте кликнуть на лайк при помощи консоли

Comment: Ну [вот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFZUf.gif), кликнул я.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно не правильно обратились по классу.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.item:not(.hide) .button')
btn.onclick = () => console.log('click')

btn.click()
```

```html
<div class="button like" status="off">
  <div class="icon" icon="like"></div>
  <span>32</span>
</div>
```

Comment: все верно он мне выдает, клик не срабатывает

Comment: @mamy, исправил, у вас был неправильный селектор. На сайте есть один элемент, который был скрыт

Comment: спасибо большое :)

Comment: @mamy если ответ правильный отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в присвоении функции методу onclick.

Вы используете строчный вариант и внутри двойных ковычек необходимо указывать одинарные ковычки для выделения строки или наоборот

т.е. onclick="nameFn('someText')" или onclick='nameFn("someText")'

```js
function like(text) {
  console.log(text)
}

document.querySelector('.like').click()
```

```html
<div class="button like" onclick="like('f9f54b8bf5fa3f979b205e61')" status="off">
<div class="icon" icon="like"></div>
<span>32</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Так это не имеет значения. Зайдите на colorhunt.co и попробуйте кликнуть на лайк при помощи консоли

Comment: @mamy Еще как имеет. Я в браузере протестировал это. Если кавычки будут одинаковые, то появися ошибка и событие клика работать не будет вообще

Comment: @mamy, перешел на ваш сайт. Спокойно кликнул на кнопку через консоль

Comment: @SwaD даже в самом сайте, если начать редактировать HTML атрибут `onclick`, то тогда будет видно, что используются одинарные кавычки (Так выглядит на сайте: `onclick='like("f9f54b8bf5fa3f979b205e61")'`). (работает на Firefox).

Comment: @ΝNL993 Я туда не ходил, смотрел что указано в вопросе. В вопросе это все в одинаковых двойных ковычках. Собственно оттуда и ответ возник ) Естественно, перед этим потестил со всех сторон

Comment: @eccs0103 Там выше по DOM есть div с классом но без события, вот он и попадает в селектор. Т.е. правильный вопрос - Не почему не срабатывает click(), а как правильно найти элемент в DOM без уникального идентификатора, что бы эмулировать click(). Ответ SanFeeD правильный в целом, однако выведет первую кнопку. А вот выбрать например 50ю...